# Bind 2 different OLAP Cube results

Tags: ssis, ssas, olap

is there a way to bind 2 OLAP Cubes with the same structure into one?
As for now I have big Datasets for past 10 years (20-50 milion records each cube) that is every day processed. For optimalization purposes I want to separate it. For exaple the data for past 8 years will be processed once and the new data will process daily. For it it would need 2 Cubes but can I merge results from it?

Edit. Im reading on blogs and forums about partitioning the data but how does it really work? Would I be able to process only the new data so I dont need to process all 30+ mil rows?

Comment: Partitions are the exact thing that you want to do.  If you want to keep it simple, create a partition for historical data and one for the current year.  You only need a source query for each partition which filters it accordingly.  This is a detailed explanation, but it's really a point and click thing for the most part: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-partition-an-ssas-cube-in-analysis-services-multidimensional/

Comment: I did create 3 partitions for my data but I can't find where I should change the process for them. I would like to make full process only for 1 partition with my latest data. Second think how does these aggregations work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing these partitions is done separately from the cube design.  One way to deal with this is by scripting out the commands and running them in a sql agent job:

1- Connect to the ssas instance, browse to the dimensions folder and hit F7 to open the object explorer details window.
2- Highlight all the dimensions, right click and select process
[image]

3- In the dialogue, select the script button and choose script action to new query window or script action to clipboard and save it someplace.  This will be the xmla command to update all the dimensions.

[image]

4- Next, navigate to the measure group in which you made the partitions and select the last partition in the group which you want to refresh daily.  Right click, select process and use the script option to create an xmla command

[image]

5- Next, select the measure group folder and select all the measure groups in the object explorer detail window, except for the partitioned group.  Right click, select process and script out the command as in step 3.

6- Now that you have all the commands, add them to a SQL Agent job with 3 xmla command steps, one to process the dimensions and the next two to process the measure groups and most recent partition.  Note that if this is running under the sql agent service account, that account will need to have permissions to process the cube.

**tip** add another job to run on the weekends which does a process full over the whole cube.  This is a little cleanup step to make sure everything stays in sync.

Comment: Great help! So basically I need to process dimensions, measures and the one partition that I need. Other partitions don't need to be refleshed or anything? Actually I run it from a DTSX Package with RapMSSQL credentials. So I could also normally paste it just there in SQL Tasks.

Comment: For point 5. I have only 1 measure group with my 3 partitions. Should i rocess the other partitons as well? Withc process should I use for the other partitions in this measure?

Comment: Well ok. I processed it all, the partition took less than 30 min. Is there a way to process faster the dimension? It took me 2.5h and the slowest action was the cube dimension that has Fact relation in dimension usage.

Comment: So, all measure groups should be processed initially.  Then process the whole cube on the weekends.  I would generally try using Update, instead of Full for dimensions, which might speed things up.  It also could be slow because of the source query.  If you are using a view and it's slow to query, you might stage the data in a physical table and read from that instead.

Comment: A already changed all my views into tables and push just the latest data there. Maybe I should add a better index. There are some non clustered indexes. If I would add a clustered index on the datetime that I use to filter partition would it help me?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - is the measure group partition slow or one of the dimensions connected to it?  Which are you trying to optimize?  The measure group partition would probably improve with the clustered index.  Test by getting a timing of querying the data before and after adding the index, but just do it in ssms, take the cube processing out of it, so you can see if that's the bottleneck